# Who am I on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, login, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid

After logging in to https://data.stackexchange.com/, I noticed my username was something like jon.doe15295. So I changed that to something more readable. But then I found that the account I had logged into was [a new account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/15294), whereas [I already had one](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/2498). I tried logging out and in with a different OpenID provider (Google instead of Google_Profile), which only gave me [yet another account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/15295).

Now I'm wondering: how do I log into [the original account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/2498)?

Comment: Did you login with the same OpenID provider with the same credentials?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I always use Google_Profile, but would like to know what I used for the original account. Its Gravatar shows it's using the same email address.

Comment: Weird, hopefully a dev or Tim Stone would be able to shed some light over this.